# Create Frameworkelement without showing it at the MainPage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I try to print a `View` without showing it on the `MainPage`.
My View has the `DataContext` of my `ViewModel`.
I tested both and binded the View as child at my `MainPage`.
That worked very well and i could use it after that as a preview for printing, too.
But it doesnt work when i just try to create it, `Meassure()` and `Arrange()` it and add set it after that as a print preview.

So I think the main problem is that it doesnt render my page.
What I try to do in the code below, is to "size" my `Frameworkelement` at least.

`FooView` is my (XamlPage) `UserControl` i want to set as a print preview. So i just need it as rendered `FrameworkElement`.

These are the Getter and Setter of my `View`.

```
public sealed partial class FooView: UserControl
{

    public FooView()
    {
            this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public new FooViewModel DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return (FooViewModel)base.DataContext;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != base.DataContext)
            {
                base.DataContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i initialize them.

```
    FooViewModel viewModel = new FooViewModel();

    viewModel.PrintDescription = new PrintDescription(
        headerLeft: string.Empty,
        headerCenter: string.Empty,
        headerRight: string.Empty,
        footerLeft: string.Empty,
        footerCenter: string.Empty,
        pageNumber: this.PrintStorage.Count,
        lastPageNumber: this.PrintStorage.Count + 1);

    // just the Content of my page not the View itself.
    viewModel.PageContent = (FrameworkElement) PageContent;

    FooView view = new FooView();
    view.DataContext = vieModel;
```

This is what i tried so far.

```
        // --- first try --- //
    FooView.InvalidateMeasure();
    FooView.InvalidateArrange();
    FooView.UpdateLayout();


    // --- second try --- //
    FooView.Measure(new Size(this.PrintDescription.Width, this.PrintDescription.PrintHeight));
    FooView.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0,  this.PrintDescription.PrintWidth, this.PrintDescription.PrintHeight));
    FooView.UpdateLayout();

        // --- third try --- //
    FooView.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    FooView.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, this.PrintDescription.PrintWidth, this.PrintDescription.PrintHeight));
    FooView.UpdateLayout();
```

But nothing of it works to render my `PrintView`. The only way I make it happen actually is to bind it first at the `MainPage` as a child. So how can i render this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not able to get your problem. Can correct your description on the top part of the question. I think I can help you i have just explore the printing.

Comment: Hello loop, it is not really about printing. Its about **creating a page without showing** it on the `MainPage`. Like rendering an image i think or prepare a XamlElement for a screenshot.

Comment: pete, what I have done sometime before is. I printed an image that has no relation to the page. So basically You give the UIElement to the printDocument whatever it is. It will print that.

Comment: Yes it worked well all the time with normal `FrameworkElement`. But for my View I use an `UserControl` in combination with a ViewModel. And if I set it as preview page it only shows me a white page. I tried it with 'Meassure()` and `Arrange()` to "size" it.

Comment: I think your problem is That your usercontrol is not able to render its contents on printer preview page. if it is then actually it does not get data from its VM or you can say it is not binded at all. If is happening then set usercontrol DataContext and other propertied that you need to be binded.

Comment: Yeah i think that it does not render too. I tested my `View` and binded it as Child on my `MainPage`. It worked very well and i could use it as preview for printing, too. And this is another proof that it doesnt render. So **my question is how can i render my `View` without binding** it at the `MainPage`.

Comment: It is simple "When you add your view to main page - then Usercontrol (View) DataContext was being set as that of page. What you have to do is set your Views DataContext appropriately. Simply set it to same DataContext as that of the page.

Comment: Hello Loop. I updated my question. I dont understand what i did wrong here.

Comment: try add FooView to a canvas first and then apply. objCanvas.InvalidateMeasure();
objCanvas.InvalidateArrange();
objCanvas.UpdateLayout(); .. I can't try it right now. I haven't slept whole night. I am using my tab.

Comment: I tried it, but it didnt worked. Maybe you know the Microsoft Example for Print they use as you said a Canvas, but they get the object with FindName(); Is there maybe anyway to create a page on the MainPage without showing it. Or maybe i try to screenshot them, but how do i render this.

Comment: I used this example :- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6

Comment: Yes i started with this, too. But they use a Canvas from an XAML Page where they bind there Elements for printing. Can I do this without showing it at the Page to get it rendered?

Comment: It is same whether you define canvas in xaml or in code behind, because ultimately a object is going to be created. I created can vas in code behind nothing related to page.

Comment: Thank you very much loop for helping me out. I found my problem and I am very happy about it. :)

Comment: great bro. what is it ?

Comment: There were 3 factors. One of them was a wrong binding. The second one was `-1` at my pagination. And the third one was wired with / about changing the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59955/discussion-between-pete-and-loop).